# Correctly yield from class using an if condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I'm trying to write a class that stripped down to the bare essential only returns the lines from a file in a form of list. This seems to be working OK when defining an iterator, for example:

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self._fn = fn
        self._fh = open(self._fn, 'rt')

    def __nextLine(self):
        return self._fh.readline().strip().split()

    def __iter__(self):
        ''' record iterator '''
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        ''' returns the next record line '''
        self.line = self.__nextLine()  # the next record
        if self.line:
            return self
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

and the file is iterated with a for loop:

```
fu = Bar('toy3.tsv')
for dat in fu:
    print(dat.line)

# prints
# ['foo', '1', '2']
# ['bar', '3', '4']
# ['foo', '5', '6']
```

However, I'd also like to include a method to only return the lines where the first column matches some value but my implementation is not going through all lines as it stops as soon as there's no match:

```
class Bar:
    ...

    def fetch(self, this):
        self.line = self.__nextLine()  # the next record
        if self.line[0] == this:
            yield self
```

The `fetch` method only returns the first line and stops, or doesn't return nothing at all if the first line is not a match, and I'm missing how to get to read the next lines:

```
fu = Bar('toy3.tsv')
for dat in fu.fetch('foo'):
    print(dat.line)

# prints
# ['foo', '1', '2']
# or prints nothing if "fetching" 'bar'
# whereas it should print the 1st and 3rd lines for 'foo'
# and the 2nd line for 'bar'
```

Any ideas on how to implement something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `yield` creates the generator, the next invocation will resume from the point last time code had yielded. So I would recommend trying something like this:

```py
class Bar:
    ...

    def fetch(self, this):
        while True:
            self.line = self.__nextLine()  # the next record
            if not self.line:
                raise StopIteration

            if self.line[0] == this:
                yield self
```

Comment: Great. Just needed to enclose the `while` loop in a `try - except` block and is now working perfectly.